# DataTable JSON Serialization with ServiceStack JsonSerializer

Tags: web-services, servicestack, jsonserializer

Does anyone know how to convert `VB.net datatable to JSON` using **ServiceStack JsonSerializer**?

On **[ServiceStack Docs](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers)** website you can find following example but this is C#, plus I cannot understand the way this works.

```
string TypeSerializer.SerializeToString<T>(T value);
void TypeSerializer.SerializeToWriter<T>(T value, TextWriter writer);

T TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(string value);
T TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<T>(TextReader reader);
```

Example datatable

```
Dim table As New DataTable
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now)
```

**Any suggestions much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStacks JSON Serializer does not support serializing DataTables directly. You would need to convert them to POCOs and serializer those.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example from which I could work up? Many thanks.

Comment: Here are a couple of links explaining how to convert a DataTable into a POCO: http://sharpdevpt.blogspot.com/2010/05/convert-datatable-into-poco-using.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354034/how-do-i-convert-a-datatable-into-a-poco-object-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: In 2022 ServiceStack.Text still doesn't support datatables. Luckily C# now supports `dynamic`. I use an extension method to convert the datatable to a `List<dynamic>` which serializes properly in ServiceStack. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794962/591285