# What is the best practice for displaying the contents of a DataSet in ASP.net MVC v1.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dataset

I am long familiar with using the ASP.net `GridView` in ASP.net forms to display the contents of `DataSet` on a web page.

What is the best practice for displaying the contents of the `DataSet` in ASP.net MVC?  I can add the `DataSet` to my `DataVew` dictionary in my controller, but I'm unsure of how to display it in the View page.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to view my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353966/datatable-instead-of-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc/1353996#1353996).  If you still have questions I'll be glad to do what I can.

Comment: As I mentioned, I added the DataSet to the DataView dictionary in the controller.  I just don't know how to display the data in a table aside from just doing a Response.Write("<table>...")

Comment: If you're looking for server controls you won't find them.  You can use css and a combination of UL/OL/LI items to layout your information or you could, as you stated, use tables.  If you're looking for something to databind to though, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

DataSets are uncommon for ASP.NET MVC applications. There are no server side controls that will allow you to display the contents of a `DataSet` as the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control in WebForms. So if you are looking for a best practice, I would suggest you put in place some server side processing that will convert your DataSet into an hierarchy of .NET objects that you would pass to a strongly typed view. Of course if this is a new application you wouldn't even bother fetching the data in a DataSet form but you would use an ORM that will directly give you .NET objects.

So once you have the objects you could take a look at the [MVCContrib Grid helper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib). Of course as you are using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 you will have to make sure to download the proper version of `MVCContrib` which is compiled against it because the current version is compiled against ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Comment: OK then.  My application must display some tabular data from a SQL server.  What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: I would recommend you reading one of the hundreds of tutorials out there: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then for MVC you want to be using Entity Framework.  Since Oracle responded to me with a lame response about Microsoft not giving them specs  ( DEVART has been doing Oracle to Entity Framework for years )

Regardless, if you have a dataset ( use a datatable if you do not need a heavy dataset ) then to make your life easy you will want to convert your dataset to a List (if you are supplied a dataset from say a web service or layer ...
Thus something like

```
    public IEnumerable<IClient> GetClient(IClient client)
    {
       DataSet dataSet = ....
         .....
      List<IClient> clients = (from c in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                 select new Client()
       .....
       return clients;
    }
```

Then in your controller:
    IClient client = (IClient)TempData["Client"];

```
        // Instantiate and instance of the repository 
        var repository = new Get_Client_Repository();
        // Set a model object to return the dynamic list from repository method call passing in the parameter data
        var model = repository.GetClient(client);

        // Call the View up passing in the data from the list
        return View(model);
```

Then in your View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<CISOnlineMVC.DAL.IClient>

   @foreach (var item in Model) {

     <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "ClientDetails", "Cis", new { id = item.ClientId }, null) |
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.LastName
    </td>
    .......
   }
```